# How to import Azure blob file into Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, bulk-insert, sql-clr, azure

Is there a way to import Blob files into sql server 2008 other than using CLR ?

The file size is around 300MB so CLR isn't efficient enough. Is there a possibility to use `BULK INSERT` or `OPENROWSET` in 2008 server?

Example in Sql Server 2017 we can do this

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL AzureDevBlobImportCred
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'st=2018-12-05T.....'

go

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE AzureDevBlobImportExternalSrc
WITH  (
    TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
    LOCATION = 'https://myStorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net', -- storage account URL
    CREDENTIAL = AzureDevBlobImportCred -- External Data Source
);
```

then we can use the external data source in bulk import

```
BULK INSERT #Mytemptable 
FROM 'filename'
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'AzureDevBlobImportExternalSrc'
);
```

So do we have something like above to import blob files in Sql Server 2008 ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy), the [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/), or even the Azure Portal to download the file to somewhere the SQL Server can read it, then use BCP or BULK INSERT to load it.

Answer (score 0):

SQL 2008 Does not directly support blob type.

for that you may reuqire to convert block and user `XML` data type or binary tyle

1) `xml` = Stores formatted XML documents -> that supports Length/ Size Up to 2GB. OR

2) `VARBINARY(max)` which Stores up to 2^31–1 bytes of binary data.

I guess `varbinary` should help you better.

Try which ever suits your need.